# API to delete a subproject in sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

Is there any way to delete a subproject in sonarqube? 
I am on SonarQube v 5.0.1

Web API documentation has - api/projects/destroy operation to delete a "project"
But I don't see any option to delete a sub project.

Appreciate the pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A sub-project can't be deleted on existing data as it is used in project aggregated measures. Values would be inconsistent.
You should exclude the sub-project when analyzing again the project.

Comment: How do I exclude a particular sub-project. any analysis parameter? Or Do you think I should just delete the parent project and re run the analysis?

Comment: You can use file inclusions/exclusions (see http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-Exclusions/Inclusions). Excluding full Maven modules should be done through native Maven features (profiles for instance).